# One of two strings as state in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-tsx, typescript-types

I have a component that looks like this:

```
export interface Props {
  // ... some props
}

export interface State {
  readonly mode: "add" | "delete"
}

export class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
  readonly state = { mode: "add" }
  // ... more component code
}
```

The problem is this throws the linting error:

```
Property 'state' in type 'ScannerScreen' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Component<Props, State, any>'.
  Type '{ mode: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<State>'.
    Types of property 'mode' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"add" | "delete"'.
```

Why does TypeScript not recognize that `"add"` or `"delete"` are strings or that `"add"` is one of the allowed types for mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to type inference -- TypeScript will infer `'add'` as `string` rather than the type `'add'`. You can fix this pretty easily by doing: `mode: "add" as "add"`. You can also use a type annotate for the state: `readonly state: State = { mode: "add" }`.

Answer (score 0):

`state` is already defined in the base component (as the error mentions).

From the typedefs it is defined as follows:

```
state: Readonly<S>;
```

Try

```
export interface Props {
  // ... some props
}

export interface State {
  readonly mode: "add" | "delete"
}

export class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
  // VSCode will have intellisense for this ...
  this.state = { mode: "add" };
  // ... more component code
}
```

If you're using VSCode it will even have the correct values in the code hints.